# Good low cost tools for woodwork

Tags: wood, tools

I'm starting to get into some woodwork for building a desk for my home and I need to purchase some tools, but I'm not really sure of what to look for to determine if a tool is of good quality.

I don't want superb top of the line tools as I won't be using them that often but I need something that will not hinder my work, and I definitely want something that will at least be good for a couple years (maybe).

I'll probably be needing

- a power drill
- a circular saw
- a jig saw
- orbital sander or belt sander

Comment: It would probably be good to ask for product recommendations in separate questions, one for each kind of tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Doweling jig](http://www.rockler.com/product.cfm?page=11294) can be useful.

or a [Pocket hole jig](http://www.rockler.com/product.cfm?page=5985).

And plenty of clamps (big ones, small ones, band clamps are nice).

For power tools I find that [Ryobi](http://www.ryobitools.com/) has decent tools for a good prices.

Comment: This is pretty much how I got started, head in every once in a while and pick up what Ryobi's I could afford, then slowly get the hand toos, and finally once my budget started freeing up I started getting bigger power tools opting for the higher quality where possible.

Answer (score 3):

My absolute favorite power drill I've bought is a [Ryobi 12V cordless](http://www.ryobitools.com/catalog/12v_lithium#/overview). They don't make the same model I have now, but the current "One+" series takes both the old 12V batteries that I have, and the newer lithium batteries (my brother has one of those - it can charge a battery in about 45 minutes!)

One of the nice things about the drill, other than the fact that it was under $60, is the magnetic tray on the bottom - it's wonderful for holding bits as you change them in and out. I use my drill as a power screwdriver all the time, so having the tray to hold screws and the bit I use to pre-drill the hole is nice.

The great thing about the cordless series is that you can get a bunch of different tools that all use the same batteries. I picked up mine at Home Depot.

Comment: @Jared Harley how long has it lasted you?

Comment: +1 - I've had pretty good luck with Ryobi tools as well.  They are a pretty good compromise between cost and quality.

Comment: I bought mine when we bought our house at the end of 2006, so almost 4 years, now, and it's still going strong - I've worn out a screwdriver bit and broken a drill bit, but the drill looks almost brand new.

Comment: +1.  Almost 7 years for mine, it's had a tough life and looks it, but it's still going strong.

Comment: Don't want to sound sarcastic, but it seems funny that a Ryobi drill is getting more attention than classic woodworking tools.

Comment: My Ryobi 14.4V drill has served me well for 7+ years.  Some of the other cordless tools are about useless or only for very small jobs: reciprocating saw and circular saw for instance.

Comment: Also must note that NiCd batteries lose their capacity over the years, especially if exposed to a lot of heat.  Fortunately, Ryobi hasn't changed their design.  New ones are cheap and still available at Home Depot.

Answer (score 3):

A good [chisel](http://woodworking.about.com/od/toolsequipment/p/chisels.htm) is in any woodworker's toolbox.

Comment: If you have a chisel, you have to have a way to keep it sharp.

Answer (score 2):

The number of [uses](http://www.popularmechanics.com/home/improvement/4306646) a [carpenter's square](http://www.acetoolonline.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=STT-45-600&utm_source=googlebase&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=StanleyTools45600MetricEnglishSteelCarpentersSquare&utm_content=StanleyTools45600MetricEnglishSteelCarpentersSquare&utm_campaign=googlebase&site=google_base) has are almost as many as the uses for the common screwdriver.

See also: http://zo-d.com/stuff/how-do-i/how-to-use-the-swanson-speed-square-as-a-framing-square.html

Answer (score 1):

Get a long and sturdy metal level.  Clamp it to plywood and use it as a straightedge for your circular saw.